# Calculating the mean of numbers in a list using for loops

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, max, min

The program shall discard the smallest and the largest numbers and calculate and display the mean of the remaining numbers. So far I figured I should import function numpy to get the mean but I don't know how to put a for-loop into it.

```
import numpy

numbers = input('Enter any list of numbers(seperated by any commas): ')

n2 = numpy.mean(numbers)
print(n2)
```

Comment: Is the use of numpy required?

Comment: Python3 already can calculate the mean using standard library. Numpy not required

Comment: Are you using python 3 or python 2?

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the step of converting the input into a list of numbers. if you're using python 2.x, input() like you're using it will return a tuple of numbers which numpy.mean() can deal with. if you're using python3, input() returns a string, which has to be parsed into numbers.

python 2.x version:

```
import numpy
numbers = input('Enter any list of numbers(seperated by any commas): ')
n2 = numpy.mean(numbers)
print(n2)
```

python 3 version:

```
import numpy
numbers = input('Enter any list of numbers(seperated by any commas): ')
num_list = [int(x) for x in numbers.split(',')]
n2 = numpy.mean(num_list)
print(n2)
```

Comment: You missed the part of removing the min and max

Comment: If the numbers are separated by commas, you'll need to split the string before converting.

Comment: @DSM `numbers` as defined in his code is set to a tuple after input is given, which has no split(). i did miss the min/max part, though. thought he might take a stab at that part once he had numbers to work with. even so, this code assumes everything is an int, which is possibly not right.

Comment: @matiaselgart: which part of his code are you referring to?  The OP calls `input`, which returns a string, and then calls `numpy.mean` on that string.  What am I missing?  [I suppose the OP could be using Python 2, despite the parentheses around print -- sometimes beginners mix syntaxes.]

Comment: @DSM i mean input() -- i'm running python2.7, which returns effectively returns a tuple, not a string like python3. his question didn't specify 2.7 vs 3, so i didn't make assumptions.

Comment: Well, you did make an assumption, in that you posted code which would only work in 2.  But you could very well be right in that assumption -- if the OP's code actually worked, he must have been using 2.

Comment: @DSM yep, you're right -- i should have shown how to do both, depending on which version. i didn't actually know that python 3 returned a different value than python 2. still learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not really clear. You want to compute the mean of an array of values, and you have a method that does it for you. Why would you need a `for` loop?

Still, your input is a string, so you must to convert it into an array before processing it. This is a bit complex, and seems beyond your question, so I'll just assume that `numbers` is already an array of numbers.

You want to remove the smallest and the greatest values, which is simply done this way:

```
numbers.remove(max(numbers))
numbers.remove(min(numbers))
```

Then just call the `mean` method:

```
numpy.mean(numbers)
```

If you really want to use a `for` loop, here is the way to compute the mean (which is what numpy does, but in a much more optimized way):

```
mean = 0
for value in numbers:
    mean += numbers
mean /= len(numbers)
```

Comment: @cricket_007 "Still, your input is a string, so you must to convert it into an array before processing it. This is a bit complex, and seems beyond your question, so I'll just assume that numbers is already an array of numbers."

Comment: Right. Missed that :)

Comment: @cricket_007 No problem. Actually, if we skip this part, I don't really get OP's problem... I think there's a misunderstanding towards the use of `mean` function, or maybe what a mean is. No offense here, it can actually become confusing when working with heavy data.

Comment: Probably just some homework problem to teach OP about finding min and max of list, then using a for loop to sum numbers, then find the mean/average